# Jupyter Lab not loading, segmentation fault

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run jupyter lab by using the command jupyter-lab in the terminal, and have been doing this for a while with no problems, but all of a sudden this error is thrown when I execute:
`zsh: segmentation fault jupyter-lab`

i have restarted my computer (MacBook air 2019, big Sur), but the problem doesn't resolve.

Comment: Could be anything from data corruption problem due to a hardware fault, to incorrectly upgraded dependencies which were compiled against another architecture. Have you tired re-installing it from scratch?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just conda uninstalled jupyterlab and then reinstalled it, but i'm having the same issue. What could this mean / is there a path to a fix?